# DataLabels formatter not working in Highcharts Sankey Diagram

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sankey-diagram

**Expected Behaviour:**
Ability to format the dataLabel in the sankey diagram

**Actual Behaviour:**
dataLabel is not getting formatted.

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function(){
        return "Abc";
    }
  }
```

**Live demo with steps to reproduce the issue:**

http://jsfiddle.net/jy0761aw/2/

**Affected browser(s):**
All browsers

Comment: I see that you posted it on **github**: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7284

Let the discussion continue there.

Comment: @KamilKulig Okay. Thats fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues. Sankey is really hard to implement I guess. Use nodeFormatter instead, formatter is just not working. Example below.

```
nodeFormatter: function (arg) {
    if (!this.point.sum) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return this.key;
    }
}
```